# using open command with NSTask

Tags: swift, nstask

I have a pretty basic understanding of NSTask in Swift and can run a few commands in  my program, but when I run open it says the file does not exist. I added the exact arguments that I use in the terminal, and I don't know what I'm missing. This is the code:

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
task.arguments = ["/Volumes/STS*/here.docx"]
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Thanks in advance. This is my first question, so have mercy if it's stupid.

Comment: NSTask does no wildcard expansion.

Comment: thank you, that explains a lot.

Comment: @MartinR, do you have any suggestion of how to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

`NSTask` doesn't expand the `*` in your path. But if you invoke the command through the shell (i.e. `/bin/bash`), it will:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", "open /Volumes/STS*/here.docx"]
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

The `-c` option tell Bash to read the commands from a string. You can check the man page for more infor.